# Advanced Custom Field Filter Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Could someone please explain why the first section of code works but not the second. I am trying to filter the content on a website based on what values have been selected in the backend on each post using Advanced Custom Fields.

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
// do not modify queries in the admin
if( is_admin() ) {
    return $query;
}

// only modify queries for 'event' post type
if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'property' ) {
    // allow the url to alter the query
    if( isset($_GET['bedrooms']) ) {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'bedrooms');
        $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['bedrooms']);
    } 
}
// return
return $query;

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

non working:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
// bail early if is in admin
if( is_admin() ){
    return;
} 


// get meta query
$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

if( isset($_GET['bedrooms']) ){
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'        => 'bedrooms',
        'value'      => $_GET['bedrooms'],
        'compare'    => '=',
    );
}

// update meta query
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

return;
}
```

Comment: you have to define post_type query  in second code section I think so

Comment: @AnandChoudhary How would I do that? thanks

Comment: @AnandChoudhary Ok I did it. Thank you. I don't get why this worked though

Comment: post_type is compulsory for more information about this check out here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/